# Routes rerender if I use a map instead of static components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have 2 routes in my app, `/validations` (which is a list) and `/validations/:id` (which is the same list focused on a particular item).

I initially wrote my routes statically and everything works (as expected):

```
<Route path="/validations/:id" component={Validations} />
<Route path="/validations" component={Validations} />
```

However, because I wanted to do some refactoring, I put the routes in an array and used a `.map` to render them. But with this, when I click on an item, the whole page rerender and I lose the scroll of the list (this is a bad UX for the user because he loses where he was in the list):

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/validations/:id',
    component: Validations,
  },
  {
    path: '/validations',
    component: Validations,
  },
]

// ...and in the JSX...

{routes.map(({ path, component }) => (
  <Route
    key={path}
    path={path}
    component={component}
  />
))}
```

Even stranger, if I remove the `key` prop of the `Route` I get back the initial behaviour (but I have a warning by React).

Did I write something wrong? Is it a react-router bug? A React one?

How can I keep the scroll of the list with my route mapping?

Here is a reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/vm71x2k46l

Comment: it's weird. It only scrolls top on the first navigation. Subsequent navigations work as expected

Comment: Yes because on subsequent navigation you are on the same route. It's to go from `/validations` to `/validations/:id` which makes the list scroll.

Comment: Yes I was going insane but I know what is going on

Answer (score 2):

I knew something was fishy because I've done this many times and I didn't get your results. So I noticed that you render your sidebar **inside** your route.

This is why it's re-rendering and setting everything to the top. Because you actually navigate to another route.

What you must do is set your Sidebar links **outside** the actual routes but **inside** the **Router** Component.

Like in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/p2r4pl2o3q

If you notice I changed the routes a bit:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    component: Index
  },
  {
    exact: true,
    path: "/validations",
    component: Validations
  },
  {
    path: "/validations/:id",
    component: Validations
  }
];
```

And then created the sidebar component and set it outside the routes

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Sidebar />
    <div style={{ marginLeft: 150 }}>{routeComponents}</div>
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Sidebar:

```
var items = Array.apply(null, Array(300)).map(function(x, i) {
  return i;
});

export default () => (
  <div
    style={{
      width: 150,
      height: "100vh",
      display: "flex",
      overflow: "auto",
      position: "absolute",
      flexDirection: "column"
    }}
  >
    {items.map((item, index) => (
      <Link to={`/validations/${index}`} key={index}>
        Item {index}
      </Link>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Now since first click the scroll doesn't reset.

**PS: Please don't mind the styling decisions I was just trying to see something work.**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it works. However as you may guess, my app is way complex than this reproduction and I can't extract the "sidebar". It's something that have to stay in the route component.

Comment: @Kerumen You can always work around it. You can always use Portals! Adjusting scroll position using the element's scrollTop is possible but quite a pain to implement and prone to bugs because of styling of said components.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to map the routes outside the App Component. Then you can add them mapped routes in the App in example **{routeComponents}**

```
const routeComponents = routes.map(({ path, component }, key) => <Route exact path={path} component={component} key={key} />);
const App = () => (<BrowserRouter><div>{routeComponents}</div></BrowserRouter>);
```

Also in the validation.js you have warning in the **{items.map ...}** line. I added the **key** prop in the link and the error gone

```
      {items.map((item, index) => (
    <Link to={`/validations/${index}`} key={index}>
      Item {index}
    </Link>
  ))}
```

here is the sandbox url https://codesandbox.io/s/8n2rlpmw0l

Comment: This is not working, the list still scroll to the top.